# C binary program for prime numbers does not want to run

Tags: c, primes

I've a problem at the execution of my program.
I compile it with gcc using: `gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -lm main.c`.
Same problem with clang and I didn't try it with tcc yet but I will when the program will be finished.
I would like it to be compilable with a c89 compiler, this explains some of my choices. I've no error at the compilation but a problem at the execution.
Like what's written in some of my comments in my code, at the execution normally, I would have an error because of a division by 0 (with the k variable) but I think I have an error in the "do...while" loop (because the rest of my function is tested), and before the by k division.
I took some hours to debug (especially with gdb (`-g` option add to the compilation command and `run -v` in gdb) but I'm still blocked.

```
/*librairies*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*main function*/
int main(){
    int N, b, i, j, h, k;
    int *t; /*pointer which will become an array (see in another after comment)*/
    float l, m, a;
    k = 0;   /*Problem with k because we will see later an error*/
    printf("Your number : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    if (N>1){
        a = sqrt(N);
        b = a; /*we convert float into int and it rounds under, normal*/ 
        t = malloc(N * sizeof(int)); /*manual dynamic memory allocation for the array to respect C89*/
        if (t==NULL){ /*t is null when you have not enough ram for a too big value for N*/
            exit(0);
        }
        for (i=1;i<N;i++){ /*function to fill the array with 2,3..N*/
            j = i + 1;
            h = i - 1;
            t[h] = j;
        }

        do{
            if (t[k]==0){
                k = k + 1;
            } else{
                for (i=1;i<N;i++){          /*problem nearby, because the division by 0 error does not come know at the execution = 0*/
                    h = i - 1;   
                    if (t[h]!=0){
                        l = (float)t[h] / (float)k; /*It's going to be a problem because in the first loop, k = 0*/
                        m = l - (int)l;
                        if (m==0.0f){
                            t[h] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (k<b);
        h = 0;
        for (i=1;i<N;i++){
            h = i - 1; 
            printf("%d\n", t[h]); /*printf to test before continuing the program*/
        }

    } else{
        printf("Your number is not valid\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Info: This program is just a personnal project to illustrate for me a math course I had (about prime numbers, and for know with the problem solved and the k problem solved, it should display:

```
Your number: N /*N is a valid (positive integer) stdin input*/
0 /*and 0 until the k<b prime values are passed but I will make them to be displayed*/
a prime number
0 
the next prime number
0 
the next prime number
0 
the next prime number
0 
the next prime number
0 
.
.
the last prime number (which can be N if N is a prime one)
```

The theorem used for this program is:

- You choose a number
- You calculate its square root
- 1, here is not a considered prime number because it divides all prime
  numbers.
- You write all the numbers from 2 to the number you choose
- You remove every multiples of prime numbers (the prime numbers used here are those under the square root) every where in the written list (here an array where we write 0 because I don't know how to use structs (list?) for now).
- The numbers which stay are all prime numbers under the one you chose (rest? sorry for my bad English)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. is NOT efficient
4. shows proper indentation
5. shows meaningful variable names
6. properly passes the allocated memory to `free_ before exiting
7. properly checks for successful execution of `scanf()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
/*librairies*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*main function*/
int main( void )
{
    size_t targetNum;
    size_t i;  // index
    size_t j;  // index



    size_t *primeArray = NULL; /*pointer which will become an array (see in another after comment)*/

    printf("Enter Your target number : ");
    if( scanf("%lu", &targetNum) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read target number\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if ( targetNum > 1 )
    {
        primeArray = malloc( targetNum * sizeof( size_t ) ); 

        if ( !primeArray )
        { 
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // initialize array of prime numbers
        for ( i = 0; i < targetNum; i++ )
        { 
            primeArray[i] = 1;
        }

        primeArray[0] = 0;
        primeArray[1] = 0;

        // find primes and zero multiples
        for( i = 0; i < targetNum; i++ )
        {
            // skip any multiples of primes (which have already been zero'd
            if( !primeArray[i] )
            {
                continue;
            }

            // zero multiples
            for( j = i+i; j < targetNum; j+=i )
            {
                primeArray[j] = 0;
            }
        }

        // print primes
        for ( i = 0; i < targetNum; i++ )
        {
            if( primeArray[i] )
            {
                printf( "%lu\n", i ); 
            }
        }

        free( primeArray );
    } 

    else
    {
        printf("Your number is not valid\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

given the following input:

```
4
```

the output is:

```
Enter Your target number : 4
2
3
```

Comment: It says It's not permitted in c89. But I agree, Your program is really good in c99 :) It learned me many things.

Comment: Ok Sorry, all your code is correct for c89 exept // comments. My apologizes.